# List view threshold exeeded error in code, but not in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I have something special (in a bad way) going on here.  When I try to create an item by code in a list, I get the error:

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

However, when I try to create an item using the default SharePoint form, the item gets created successfully.

Now, the list has less than 100 items.  The threshold limit is set to 5000 items.  The list has no versioning enabled.

The weird thing is that this works in default SharePoint, but errors out in custom code.  My code below isn't any different:

```
bool intAllowUpdates = list.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
list.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPListItem selectedItem = list.AddItem();
// Set the data for fields using selectedItem[""] = "";
selectedItem.Update();
list.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = intAllowUpdates;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing list View Lookup threshold. Check if you have more than 8 lookup fields?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work out.  The list is relatively small, and there is only one lookup field.  The is ruled out.  Interestingly, this issue only happens with code, but not with SharePoint's default new item form.  I mean, I can't think of a scenario where this would happen.